# I want to show native alert box for iphone using jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, jquery-mobile

I have written following code to show a native alert box on iPhone using jQuery mobile + HTML.

```
alert('ID not Match !');
```

It is giving me the native alert, but I want to be able to change the title.
Please tell me how to change/give a title to an alert box.

This is how the alert is displayed on iOS:
[image: alert box as displayed on iOS]

also see my custom dialog. But it does not look like a native alert/ dialog:
[image]

My custom dialog does not look native. Please help me.

Comment: You may need to create custom dialog for it.

Comment: i have created custom dialog box but it doesn't give me native UI

Comment: Does your document have `<title></title>` tags?

Comment: Then that's the way it is. With good old `alert()` all you can specify is the text.

Comment: `alert('ID not Match !');` This much is my code. and its showing me default html page name as title of alert which i have not given.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="sure" data-title="Are you sure?">
  <div data-role="content">
    <h3 class="sure-1">???</h3>
    <p class="sure-2">???</p>
    <a href="#" class="sure-do" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-rel="back">Yes</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="c" data-rel="back">No</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this:

```
function areYouSure(text1, text2, button, callback) {
  $("#sure .sure-1").text(text1);
  $("#sure .sure-2").text(text2);
  $("#sure .sure-do").text(button).on("click.sure", function() {
    callback();
    $(this).off("click.sure");
  });
  $.mobile.changePage("#sure");
}
```

You can use these wherever you need the confirmation dialog:

```
areYouSure("Are you sure?", "---description---", "Exit", function() {
  // user has confirmed, do stuff
});
```

And also refer this : 
http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/popup.html

Comment: Does your Dialog gives me Native UI as iPhone dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You can use phonegap/cordova that will enable you to call `navigation.notification.alert` and that will give you the native alert box

You can find more info about it here
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification

Answer (score 0):

This is handled like this for security reasons. You'll need to use a custom dialog.